# Dotnet aspnet -codegenerator failed for dotnet core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code and run

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries
```

After that, I got error

```
Building project ...
Scaffolding failed.
Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.
To see more information, enable tracing by setting environment variable 'codegen_trace' = 1.
RunTime 00:00:03.47
```

I try to add package using

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design --version 3.1.0
```

and Get error

```
 Writing C:\Users\tdong.BCFSA\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA5E0.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design' into 
project 'D:\Work\Testing\Movies\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for D:\Work\Testing\Movies\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie.csproj...
error: Package NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 
(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0 does not support any target frameworks.
error: Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design' is incompatible with 'all' 
frameworks in project 'D:\Work\Testing\Movies\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie.csproj'.
```

Comment: hope you're well. What does your csproj look like? It seems like your target framework may be pointing to a .NET framework while you are trying to use .NET Core.